# Converting log4j.properties file for Tomcat to work with Log4j2

Tags: tomcat, logging, log4j2

I'm trying to configure Tomcat 8 to use Log4j2 for logging.

I've found this reference for [Logging in Tomcat using Log4j](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j). It provides a sample log4j.properties file that configures Log4j to match Tomcat's internal logging. Most of this looks pretty straightforward to convert for Log4j2, but the section at the end that maps loggers to appenders has me stumped:

```
# Configure which loggers log to which appenders
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost] = INFO, LOCALHOST
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager] =\
  INFO, MANAGER
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager] =\
  INFO, HOST-MANAGER
```

Has anyone converted this configuration to work with Log4j2? I've been working from the Log4j2 configuration documentation and have read through the [Log4j2 Architecture page](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/architecture.html), but I haven't found much material on how to do this sort of container mapping in Log4j2.

I suppose I could do a separate configuration for each container, but I'd prefer to keep it in one place, as in the sample Log4j configuration.

Comment: Have you tried asking on the tomcat-users mailing list? http://tomcat.apache.org/lists.html

That's where the experts hang out and you're most likely to get an accurate response.

Comment: Likely your only chance of using log4j2 with tomcat will be to use the log4j 1.x bridge. http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/migration.html

Comment: @Brett Okken this is no longer true in 8.5.11 +. extras for july was terminated since 8.5.11 and only thing you need to use log4j2 is to use David Kellerman script and 3 jars from log4j2 (core,api,july) (plus configfile)

Answer (score 17):

After asking this question, I spent some more time with setting up log4j2, and this is the
`log4j2.xml` file I came up with. It mimics the configuration
described in [Logging in Tomcat using Log4j](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j). It uses multiple loggers to route messages
to separate log files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration status="info">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="logdir">${sys:catalina.base}/logs</Property>
    <Property name="layout">%d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n</Property>
  </Properties>
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="${layout}"/>
    </Console>
    <RollingFile name="CATALINA"
        fileName="${logdir}/catalina.log"
        filePattern="${logdir}/catalina.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="${layout}"/>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 MB"/>
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
    </RollingFile>
    <RollingFile name="LOCALHOST"
        fileName="${logdir}/localhost.log"
        filePattern="${logdir}/localhost.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="${layout}"/>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 MB"/>
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
    </RollingFile>
    <RollingFile name="MANAGER"
        fileName="${logdir}/manager.log"
        filePattern="${logdir}/manager.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="${layout}"/>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 MB"/>
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
    </RollingFile>
    <RollingFile name="HOST-MANAGER"
        fileName="${logdir}/host-manager.log"
        filePattern="${logdir}/host-manager.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="${layout}"/>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 MB"/>
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="CATALINA"/>
    </Root>
    <Logger name="org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost]"
        level="info" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="LOCALHOST"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager]"
        level="info" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="MANAGER"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager]"
        level="info" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="HOST-MANAGER"/>
    </Logger>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

However, getting this to work properly required getting
a bunch of other files
configured correctly. The [tomcat 7 internal logging with log4j2.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28446085/tomcat-7-internal-logging-with-log4j2-xml)
posting from Paramita Banerjee was helpful with this.

This file goes in `CATALINA_HOME/bin/`:

- `tomcat-juli.jar`

If you're pulling this from the Maven repository, you'll get a file
named something like `tomcat-extras-juli-8.0.15.jar` (the current
version when I wrote this). However, it needs to be renamed to
`tomcat-juli.jar` – the Tomcat setup scripts use that name in
setting up the CLASSPATH.

These files go in `CATALINA_HOME/lib/`:

- `commons-logging-1.2.jar`
- `log4j-1.2-api-2.1.jar`
- `log4j-api-2.1.jar`
- `log4j-core-2.1.jar`
- `log4j-jcl-2.1.jar`
- `log4j-jul-2.1.jar`
- `log4j-web-2.1.jar`
- `tomcat-juli-adapters-8.0.15.jar`

`log4j-web-2.1.jar` may not be needed here (it may just need to be deployed with your web application) – its use is described in
[Using Log4j 2 in Web Applications](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html).
`log4j-1.2-api-2.1.jar` is needed only if you have applications that use
the older log4j 1.2 interface.

In `CATALINA_BASE/conf`, I disabled `logging.properties`.

I used the following `setenv.sh` script to define the `CLASSPATH` and
`LOGGING_MANAGER` environment variables correctly for Tomcat. It goes in either
`CATALINA_BASE/bin` or into `CATALINA_HOME/bin`. (I put it in
`CATALINA_HOME`/bin.) It is executed by Tomcat's startup scripts if it's
present. You might prefer something simpler, but this is in keeping with
the style of the startup scripts.

```
LOG4J_JARS="log4j-core-2.1.jar log4j-api-2.1.jar log4j-jul-2.1.jar"

# make log4j2.xml available
if [ ! -z "$CLASSPATH" ] ; then CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH": ; fi
CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH""$CATALINA_BASE"/lib

# Add log4j2 jar files to CLASSPATH
for jar in $LOG4J_JARS ; do
  if [ -r "$CATALINA_HOME"/lib/"$jar" ] ; then
    CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH":"$CATALINA_HOME"/lib/"$jar"
  else
    echo "Cannot find $CATALINA_HOME/lib/$jar"
    echo "This file is needed to properly configure log4j2 for this program"
    exit 1
  fi
done

# use the logging manager from log4j-jul
LOGGING_MANAGER="-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager"
```

As Nick mentioned in his response, there's also the output to the
access log. I haven't tried to do anything with that, either.

I hope others find this useful. In retrospect, it seems pretty
straightforward. However, there are a lot of parts that have to be 
“just right” for it to work, and that was a challenge (at least for a
newbie).

Comment: Your log4j2.xml file was spot on, but a lot of your configuration is superfluous. I used the steps here instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35618384/399105

Comment: I made a few adjustments for my own needs, such as only doing time based rolling (and not size based) and compressing logs by default: https://gist.github.com/bmaupin/475a0cd6e8b374d876f5085846761fb6

Comment: thanks for sharing this solution - got log4j2 2.8.1 working on tomcat 9

Comment: since tomcat 8+ works without extras you need only log4j-core-2.8.1.jar, log4j-api-2.8.1.jar, log4j-jul-2.8.1.jar and log4j2.xml in lib. With above script inside setenv.sh to get things done - tested on 8.5.11

Comment: Where are the tomcat-juli and especially the tomcat-juli-adapters.jar for Tomcat 8.5 and above? I can't seem to find them

Comment: For Apache Tomcat 8.5 and later the dependencies are simplified. Check https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-appserver/index.html

Answer (score 4):

I followed the reference for [Logging in Tomcat using Log4j](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j) and added tomcat-juli.jar to the bin dir and I also added tomcat-juli-adapters.jar to the lib dir.
Afterwards i added the log4j-api-2.1.jar, log4j-core-2.1.jar and log4j-1.2-api-2.1.jar to the lib dir.

After that I added log4j2.xml to the lib dir. I kept the configuration fairly simple using a time and size based rolling configuration that zips the archived logs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="catalina" packages="">

    <Appenders>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="catalina"
            fileName="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/catalina.log"
            filePattern="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/catalina/$${date:yyyy-MM}/catalina-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.zip">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss}: %5p (%F:%L) - %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="100" />
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <!-- default loglevel for emaxx code -->
        <logger name="org.apache.catalina" level="info">
            <appender-ref ref="catalina" />
        </logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <appender-ref ref="catalina" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This way you'll get all logging in the catalina.log.
I'm still working on getting the accessLog to do the same.
EDIT: I found [this](http://www.shadegrowncode.com/) site. this way you can direct access logging to the catalina.log. (I couldn't get it to log to it's own appender)

I didn't worry about the logging for manager and host manager, since we don't have them in production environments, but they might just log to the catalina.log too. I haven't tested it.

This was tested on tomcat-7.0.42, it should work in tomcat8 too.

Answer (score 0):

For system properties you need to prefix variables with "sys:" it indicates System Properties

Example:

appender.file.fileName=${sys:catalina.base}/logs/XXX.log

for more information go through below link 
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution